# jQuery: $(element).text() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically generating content - div's with links in them. Link should bring up a popup containing link's text when clicked (showMyText function). Instead I get an empty string :(

Why isn't this working? I've searched Stackoverflow and jQuery API and it should work.

```
function a(){
    var div=document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML='<a class="aClass" href="javascript:showMyText(this)">Link Text</a>';

    var parent_div=document.getElementById('dinamicni_div');
    parent_div.appendChild(div);    
}

function showMyText(link){
    var txt=$(link).text();
    alert(txt);
}
```

Comment: Because `link` is no dom node, has no valid selector or there is no element which matches the selector.

Comment: How can i then access the (a href) element which called the function? Using keyword _this_ it doesn't work either (I think _this_ is referencing to function itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using jQuery to get the `text()` why not use it for everything else too?

```
function a() {
    var $div = $("<div></div>");
    var $a = $("<a></a>")
        .attr("href", "#")
        .addClass("aClass")
        .text("Link text")
        .appendTo($div);

    $div.appendTo("#dinamicni_div");
}

$("#dinamicni_div").on('click', '.aClass', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UN9wx/2/)

Comment: Because I just started to explore jQuery :) Thanks, this looks SO great!

Comment: @PrimožKralj, this is really the best answer because it totally eliminates any inline JavaScript by leveraging the power of jQuery.

Comment: Sparky, I'm making changes as we speak (including eliminating inline JS) :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
div.innerHTML='<a class="aClass" onclick="showMyText(this)">Link Text</a>';
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8U7ZE/)**.

Comment: Wow, onclick vs href.. Thanks

Comment: @PrimožKralj, Use neither `onclick=` or `href="javascript:"`.  As long as jQuery is involved, easily avoid using the inline JavaScript entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different approach and use the "live" method which will allow you to bind a click event to the dynamically created element once it is inserted into the DOM

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dinamicni_div').html('<a class="aClass" href="#">Link Text</a>');
  $(".aClass").live('click',function(){
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated. You shouldn't use it as it will eventually be removed. Use `on()` for 1.7+, otherwise `delegate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I find that `text()` stops working after the user manually edits the text area. `val()` continues to work as expected.