# Checking for HTML markup in an RSS feed and removing

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Hi there I've been writing an app that is a list of RSS feeds. I've been connecting my buttons to their object counter part (button that shows specific feed E.G BBC button shows the BBC rss feed, Guardian shows Guarian news and hides BBC) however looking at the containers they become quite skewed due to a handlebars helper I'm incorporating to make the feeds look nice.
The helper allows me to shorten feed descriptions and end the shortened version with ellipses. The reason this has caused an issue is because one of the feeds has HTML within it's description meaning after the maxLength HTML markup from the descriptions is still being added to the page. This makes my containers have additional unwanted HTML elements.
I hope this is explanatory enough, the TL;DR is HTML returned in RSS descriptions is adding aditional unwanted HTML to my page. How to fix?

My helper method:

```
    handlebars.registerHelper("rssDesc", function(results) {                
    var maxLength = 164;        

    //this checks for multiple descriptions and shows first
    if(Array.isArray(results)) {
        results = results[0];
    }

    //this checks to see if text contains html markup and converts it to text HOWEVER doesn't work yet. T_T
    if(results.indexOf("<") > -1) {
        results = $(results).text();    
    }
    results = results.substring(0, maxLength);

    return results.substring(0, Math.min(results.length, results.lastIndexOf(" "))) + " ...";
});
```

handlebars template

```
<div class="rssButtons">
    <a class="1">news 1</a>
    <a class="2">news 2</a>
    <a class="3">news 3</a>
    <a class="4">news 4</a>
</div> 
<div class="rssContainer">
    {{#each items}}
    <div class="tab" id="{{this.name}}">
    {{#each data}}
    <div class="news-item">
    <span class="news-title">{{title}}</span>
    <span class="news-publishing">{{publishingDate}}</span>
    <span class="news-description">{{{rssDesc description}}}</span>
</div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) the jquery way is the easiest

```
// retrieves all the text from a string of html.    
jQuery(html).text();
```

Comment: yeah I tried that with the second if, which for some funky reason has started working. It seems to present an issue when an RSS feed displays a Bulletpoint. Such confuse but thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the link provided here -> [jQuery: $(element).text() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263090/jquery-element-text-doesnt-work)

I read that sometimes the .text(); doesn't always play nice if it's not first. As of two hours of implementation of the .text(); at the beginning of the helper (under the var) things have been great!

Comment: As of right now this doesn't work ^ I've received another error.